# LinAlgError Singular Matrix when implementing logistic regression

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am trying to implement a logistic regression model, but when I try to print the results I'm getting an error that I've looked up and tried to figure out how to solve, but haven't been able to.

Here's what that looks like:

```
#Columns
columns = new_df[['DIABETES_NO','DIABETES_INSULIN', 'DIABETES_NON-INSULIN', 'bmi_cat_0','bmi_cat_gte40','bmi_cat_lt40',
                 'albumin_cat_0', 'albumin_cat_gt3.5', 'albumin_cat_lt3.5', 'SMOKE_No', 'SMOKE_Yes',
                 'age_cat_0', 'age_cat_gte65', 'age_cat_lt65', 'SEX_male', 'SEX_female']]
```

```
#Model 1 Target Variable (Mortality)

X = columns
y = new_df['Mortality']

logit_model=sm.Logit (y,X)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary2())
```

```
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: 0.014645
         Iterations: 35
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-0a3dafc9126f> in <module>
      5 
      6 logit_model=sm.Logit (y,X)
----> 7 result=logit_model.fit()
      8 print(result.summary2())

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
   1832         bnryfit = super(Logit, self).fit(start_params=start_params,
   1833                 method=method, maxiter=maxiter, full_output=full_output,
-> 1834                 disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)
   1835 
   1836         discretefit = LogitResults(self, bnryfit)

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\discrete\discrete_model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
    218         mlefit = super(DiscreteModel, self).fit(start_params=start_params,
    219                 method=method, maxiter=maxiter, full_output=full_output,
--> 220                 disp=disp, callback=callback, **kwargs)
    221 
    222         return mlefit # up to subclasses to wrap results

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py in fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, fargs, callback, retall, skip_hessian, **kwargs)
    471             Hinv = cov_params_func(self, xopt, retvals)
    472         elif method == 'newton' and full_output:
--> 473             Hinv = np.linalg.inv(-retvals['Hessian']) / nobs
    474         elif not skip_hessian:
    475             H = -1 * self.hessian(xopt)

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in inv(a)
    530     signature = 'D->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'd->d'
    531     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 532     ainv = _umath_linalg.inv(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    533     return wrap(ainv.astype(result_t, copy=False))
    534 

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     87 
     88 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 89     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     90 
     91 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

I tried to set the method='bfgs' but I get NaN, for all areas except for the Coeff column.

Here's what that looks like:

```
#Model 1 Target Variable (Mortality)

X = columns
y = new_df['Mortality']

logit_model=sm.Logit (y,X)
result=logit_model.fit(method='bfgs')
print(result.summary2())
```

```
Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
         Current function value: 0.014671
         Iterations: 35
         Function evaluations: 36
         Gradient evaluations: 36
                         Results: Logit
=================================================================
Model:              Logit            Pseudo R-squared: 0.090     
Dependent Variable: Mortality        AIC:              329.5189  
Date:               2020-10-15 19:32 BIC:              402.1568  
No. Observations:   10549            Log-Likelihood:   -154.76   
Df Model:           9                LL-Null:          -170.03   
Df Residuals:       10539            LLR p-value:      0.00035468
Converged:          0.0000           Scale:            1.0000    
-----------------------------------------------------------------
                          Coef.  Std.Err.  z  P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
-----------------------------------------------------------------
DIABETES_NO              -1.3211      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
DIABETES_INSULIN         -0.1911      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
DIABETES_NON-INSULIN     -0.2797      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
bmi_cat_0                -0.0321      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
bmi_cat_gte40            -1.0971      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
bmi_cat_lt40             -0.6626      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
albumin_cat_0            -1.7288      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
albumin_cat_gt3.5        -0.7371      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
albumin_cat_lt3.5         0.6740      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
SMOKE_No                 -1.0509      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
SMOKE_Yes                -0.7410      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
age_cat_0                -0.0321      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
age_cat_gte65            -0.0337      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
age_cat_lt65             -1.7261      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
SEX_male                 -1.2519      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
SEX_female               -0.5400      nan nan   nan    nan    nan
=================================================================
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

It is quite clear that you do not understand how to handle categorical variables. You include a whole set of one-hot encoded dummies (e.g. including `SEX_male` and `SEX_female` together) per categorical variable, essentially introducing multiple constants to your regression, hence singular matrix error.

Comment: Yes, clearly I am not understanding something here, so what do I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: The point is that the problem is not with the package itself but rather with the lack of understanding of the underlying process on your part, which is logistic regression with categorical predictors. Therefore I can only advise you to brush up your knowledge in that area.